# Stop div from sliding past the top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im using media queries on my footer. My footer is fixed to the bottom. When the user clicks a toggle a footer container slides up from the bottom of the page which works great for desktop and tablet. My issue is that on a smartphone the container slides up and then goes past the top of the page.

My solution would be to use JQuery to stop this div sliding past the top of the page and then the user can scroll down the container if need be. Feel free to suggest other solutions though.

The trouble is i haven't got a clue how i would go about doing this.

Let me know if you need more info...

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/danieljoseph/zgrhs11u/2/

CSS:

```
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

footer {
position:fixed;
z-index:10;
left:0;
background:#000;
bottom:0;
z-index:1;
}

.container {
width:100%;
clear:both;
display:block;
}

ul {
width:25%;
float:left;
height:100%;
padding:0;
}

.footToggle {
cursor:pointer;
color:#fff;
height:50px;
float:left;
background:#f00;
}

footer > div:nth-child(2) {
background:#f1f1f1;
display:none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
footer > div ul {
width:100%;
}
}
```

HTML:

```
<footer class="container">

<div class="container">
<a class="footToggle">CLICK HERE</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
   <ul>
  <li><a href="#">text here</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">text here</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">text here</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">text here</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">text here</a></li>
   </ul>

   <ul>
  <li><a href="#">text here</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">text here</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">text here</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">text here</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">text here</a></li>
   </ul>

   <ul>
  <li><a href="#">text here</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">text here</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">text here</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">text here</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">text here</a></li>
   </ul>

   <ul>
  <li><a href="#">text here</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">text here</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">text here</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">text here</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">text here</a></li>
  </ul>

  </div>

<footer>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(".footToggle").click(function(){
$("footer div:nth-child(2)").slideToggle();
$(".footToggle").toggleClass('changeBack');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will prevent the footer from overflowing from the top of the page. You can change the max-height attribute below to fit your need.

```
footer.container {
   max-height: 160px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

This must be added in your mobile media query part.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  footer.container {
       max-height: 160px;
       overflow-y: scroll;
    }
}
```

Pure Jquery based solution,

```
// Footer
$(".footToggle").click(function(){
    $("footer div:nth-child(2)").slideToggle();
    $("footer").css({ "maxHeight" : $(window).height(), "overflowY" : "scroll" });
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your suggestion. This does work and would be a great plan B but i'm hoping i can make the footer slide up to the top of the page.

Comment: @DanielJoseph I've updated the answer :) Now it's based on the window height :)